# How to change Storybook component wrapper name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I recently updated to Storybook 6.0 and am playing around with [controls](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/controls).

I would like the source code in the preview to mirror the actual code:

`buttonArgs.stories.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions'

import { Button } from '../src/index'

export default {
  title: 'ButtonArgs',
  component: Button,
  argTypes: {
    type: {
      description: 'Style type of button.',
      control: {
        type: 'select',
        options: ['primary', 'secondary', 'tertiary'],
      },
      name: 'type',
      table: {
        defaultValue: {
          summary: 'primary',
        },
      },
      type: { type: 'select', required: true },
    },
    text: {
      description: 'Text value of the button.',
      table: {
        defaultValue: {
          summary: 'Button',
        },
      },
      type: { text: 'string', required: true },
    },
  },
}

const Template = (args) => (
  <div>
    <Button onClick={action('onClick')} {...args} />
  </div>
)

export const Default = Template.bind({})
Default.args = {
  type: 'primary',
  text: 'Button',
}
```

But then the "source code" it displays looks like this (see image):

```
<div>
  <Wrapper
    onClick={() => {}}
    text="Button"
    type="primary"
  />
</div>
```

[image: storybook]

Is there a way I can change the `Wrapper` value to match the code (i.e. 'Button')? I've scoured through their docs and GitHub, and am coming up empty.

Answer (score 1):

There are effectively 2 solutions, depending on your preferences for code preview (which can change case by case).

**1. Show the exact code you wrote.**

You can tell Storybook to render the example code exactly as you have written it, by using the story parameters options.

In your example add:

```
Default.parameters = {
    docs: {source: {type: "code"}}
};
```

The downside of this, is that it will be shown exactly as you have written it (so will display {...args} instead of the resolved props from your controls).

**2. Correct the display name of your component**

To correct the name of your component, you should ideally rework your code such that the imported component is named correctly. It is likely that you have written your component with the name Button, then after applying hocs have assigned it to the variable name Wrapper. This means the exported component will have the default display name "Wrapper". Instead, you can name your base component "ButtonCore", and your HOC wrapped component "Button".

Alternatively, you can override the display name before exporting in your Button source file, or after importing into your story file:

```
import { Button } from '../src/index'

Button.displayName = "Button";
```